# Mongodb nested find

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My database schema is somewhat like

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"), 
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-03-10T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "user_list" : [
        {
            "id" : "a", 
            "some_flag" : 1,  
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "b",
            "some_flag" : 0, 
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to do is get the document where **id is b** & **some_flag for the user b is 0**.

My query is

```
db.collection.find({
  'createdAt': {
    $gte: new Date()
  },
  'user_list.id': 'b',
  'user_list.some_flag': 1
}).sort({
  createdAt: 1
})
```

When I run the query in shell. It returns the doc with id 1(which it shouldn't as the value of some_flag for b is 0)

The thing happening here is,

> the query **'user_list.id': user_id** matches with the nested object where "id" : b
>
> **'user_list.some_flag': 1** is matched with some_flag of nested object where "id": a (as the value of some_flag is 1 here)

What modifications should I make to compare the id & some_flag for the same nested object.

P.S. the amount of data is quite large & using aggregate will be a performance bottleneck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `$elemMatch` otherwise `mongoDB` queries are applied independently on array items, so in your case `'user_list.some_flag': 1` will be matched to array item with id `a` and `'user_list.id': 'b'` will match array item with id `b`. So essentially if you want to query on array field with `and` logic use `$elemMatch` as following:

```
db.collection.find({
  'createdAt': {
    $gte: new Date()
  },
  user_list: {$elemMatch: {id: 'b', some_flag: 1}} // will only be true if a unique item of the array fulfill both of the conditions.
}).sort({
  createdAt: 1
})
```

Comment: using $elemMatch will find only entries where all properties compared match, so in your example the query I gave will return 0 entries as neither have _id:'b' AND some_flag: 1

Comment: The OP tells the query returns items which it should not supposed to return and the records user gave is just for sampling as it is mentioned on the question also. So main idea is to show usage of `$elemMatch` and explain why the regular querying is not working.

Comment: Ya sorry, I meant for that comment to be appended to my answer below. 
They already explains what their query is doing wrong so it seems they understand that part of the issue.

Thank you for the more in-depth description though

Comment: Thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 3):

you need to try something like :

```
db.collection.find({
    'createdAt': {
        $gte: new Date()
    },
    user_list: {
        $elemMatch: {
            id: 'b',
            some_flag: 1
        }
    }
}).sort({
  createdAt: 1
});
```

This will match only user_list entries where _id is b and someflag is 1